# What is this object/hero/troop?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was looking through some of my defense records recently, and a particular attack caught my eye:

[image: Defense log screenshot]

What interested me was the 'troop' beside the archers. This is what it looks like in the replay (pretty much the same):

[image: Replay screenshot]

I don't know what this troop/hero/object is. My only theory is that it may be donated troops from a previous clan (as this player has no clan).

**So, what is this mysterious item?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the icon for clan castle troops.

When a player is in a clan, you would usually see the clan shield instead, but if that same player left the clan before attacking your base, you will see this icon instead.

Here is an example of how it would have looked like if the player was still in a clan (picture from the [wikia](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Symbol)):

[image]